# Не могу войти в аккаунт google

Tags: google-play

Не могу войти аккаунт из за двухэтапной аунтефикации после сброса до заводских настроек.
 Пароль знаю, привязанный номер тоже знаю, вообщем все данные знаю

Когда хотел пройти эту двухэтапную аунтефикацию, то просит открыть уведомления на моем телефоне, но ничего не происходит и закрывается сам гугл хром.
Когда опять хотел зайти в аккаунт, то уже не просит никакие уведомления, т.к ПРЕВЫШЕН ЛИМИТ УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ ОТ Google. Сколько ждать?

Что делать?

Comment: "после сброса до заводских настроек" - после сброса чего, телефона, брайзера, компа, учетки?

Comment: А вопрос по тематике сайта?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуй. У меня самого раньше были проблемы с доступом и банально с входом в мою учётную запись **Google**. Я на форумах и статьях толком нечего не нашёл и делал всё относительно сам. Ну вот пункты которые я делал по порядку во самого нужного тебе результата.

## Зайди с **компьютера** в свою учётную запись

Да, именно с компьютера. Потому-что сервис **Google** иногда затрудняются отправить сообщение с запросом на *двух этапную аутентификацию* на тот телефон, с которого ,собственно, запрос и пришёл.

### Сделай запрос на отправку SMS на твой телефон

Если первый способ не подходит, попробуй в меню **Выбрать другой способ входа**, выбери отправку SMS на телефон. Было бы неплохо, если на Ваш аккаунт было привязано более 1 телефона, потому что Вы можете столкнуться с проблемой не от **Google** а от Вашего оператора, который может заблокировать сообщение (Да такое тоже бывает я даже симку менял).

### Использовать 1 из 10 резервных ключей

Да есть те люди который действительно бояться, что потеряют свой аккаунт (особенно если человек связан с **Google** из-за работы или ещё каких либо важных причин. **Google** относительно недавно добавило пользователю возможность получить 10 резервных ключей, которые нужны именно в Вашей ситуации. Посмотрите загрузки Вашего устройства и если так есть **Exel** или **.PDF** файл, где и будут Ваши резервные ключи.

---

Ну этой цепочкой я смог восстановить свой доступ к аккаунту. Сможете сделать ли это Вы? Я искренне надеюсь. Удачи Вам. **SeeSharp**