не получается восстановить аккаунт гугл
пытался восстановить аккаунт большое количество раз, пароли не подходят, а после нажатия кнопки "Забыли пароль?" говорит, что мало информации и не дает войти

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! На какие темы тут задают вопросы => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic // по вашему вопросу обратитесь в службу поддержки гугл, указав достаточно информации, которая будет запрошена у вас. Удачи

Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867918/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%82-google
